# Is there any way to turn off indent guide line for comments in sublime?

Tags: sublimetext3, indentation

My sublime editor add indent guide line for both codes and comments. However I find it's rather visually unpleasant---I just want the indent guide line for the body of loops: between `do` and `endo`. Then how to set it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no, you can't selectively display indent guides based on the type of code. Indent guides can be modified for the entire view (the whole file), but not for certain parts of it.